# insert value for ${xxx} in bean in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have defined a bean in `XML` like

```
<bean class="some.class.Clazz">
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
</bean>
```

after that, I want to insert the value in java, I have the code like:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("main.xml");
Properties ftpSessionProps = new Properties();
ftpSessionProps.setProperty("user", "first");

StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
env.getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("pops", ftpSessionProps));
ctx.setEnvironment(env);
ctx.refresh();
ctx.start();
```

But it never works...

and I tries to add

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

in the `xml` file, it gave me the logs:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'user' in string value "${user}"

Any suggestions? Or recommendations for books or articles?

Thanks!

### UPDATE

It seems that the class 'ConfigurableApplicationContext' can't be refreshed with the new `env`. So we should be careful choosing the `context` class. The one `AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext` could be refreshed and you should only initialize it with an empty resource. And set the `configLocation` manually after you set the `environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor with `String` parameter automatically processes the file and fails because the environment hasn't been set yet.

You need to use [zero-parameter constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext--), call `setConfigLocation`, `setEnvironment` and then `refresh` and `start`:

```
AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(); // init empty
Properties ftpSessionProps = new Properties();
ftpSessionProps.setProperty("user", "first");

StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
env.getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("pops", ftpSessionProps));
ctx.setEnvironment(env);
ctx.setConfigLocation("classpath:main.xml"); // set the config here
ctx.refresh();
ctx.start();
```

Comment: This is what I want! thanks! But the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` should be changed to `AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicaitonContext`, otherwise there is no way to `setConfigLocation`. and also the param of `setConfigLocation` should be `classpath:main.xml` instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate that "user" property of "some.class.Clazz" Bean, you may use "**PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**" for which you have to use property file **locations** as an attribute.It's a subclass that resolves ${...} placeholders against system properties and environment variables.

```
<bean id="dataProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:myproject.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>
```

This bean definition will find the value for **${driverClassName}** in **myproject.properties** file under classpath of the application.

Corresponding Properties File

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema
username=root
password=1234
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kumar, your answer did help, but it's not actually what I want. But it was explained very good.